# Finding level curves of function with absolute value

Tags: multivariable-calculus, curves

I'm trying to find the level curves that correspond to this function:

[image]

I know that the first step is to set the function equal to a random *k*, and after that try different values to see if it looks similar to a known equation but I haven't been able to make much progress beyond that. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Please do not upload images of equations (which cannot be searched).  Instead, take the time to typeset all equations as a courtesy to solvers.

Comment: Sorry! Didn't know about that, will do next time

Answer (score 0):

Here they are... pretty straightforward:

[image]

or...

[image]

Comment: "Technically" the level curves all lie in the same plane. You've shown the surface ruled by these curves. The level curves are the projection of these cross sections down into the domain.

Answer (score 0):

That just gives you $$|x| + y=c$$ or, rewritten, $$y = c - |x|.$$ Surely you know what this looks like for various values of $c$?

Comment: Thanks! Yes I do, just thought there was something else to be done.